# Should I use an if or switch Statement? Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement, switch-statement

I have always wondered but can't find a definitive answer. When should I use either an 'if' or 'switch' statement. When is one better than the other?

For example I could do:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            //Stuff
            break;

        case 1:
            //Stuff
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

//OR

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //Stuff
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //Stuff 
    }
}
```

This is just an example, but I'm sure in different situations to this it would matter differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is a subjective question.  The answer is really up to you.

For my own code, I like using `switch` statements as it's pretty clear that what is happening is the result of some condition that can do other things if the condition is different.

But if the code underneath a `switch` `case:` statement is rather lengthly or convoluted, then for my own code I do the second thing: the `if (buttonIndex == 0) {` bit.

Comment: It should also be noted that `switch` may theoretically be faster. Doesn't make much of a difference if you only have a few cases though.

Comment: As @Dani mentioned in his answer, `switch` takes O(1) time to execute while the `if ... else if ... else if ...` will be O(n) where n is the number of conditions. One of the reasons for this is that with the `if ... else` constructions, the conditions must be evaluated every time they are hit whereas the `switch` `case` is a table lookup.

Comment: Check Dani's comment. Its based on algorithm complexity.

Answer (score 13):

In this case this doesn't matter. The reason switch exists is that it's faster than if. If you write a long code of `if ... else if ... else if ...` it will perform slower than switch because `if` does iterative search (O(n)) while `switch` does table based lookup (O(1))

Answer (score 4):

If you are only checking if one variable is of a certain value (buttonIndex == 1) and doing this for several values you'd be better of using a `switch`.

However if you are using some more complex conditions (maybe even including functions in the condition), well then you should use `if statements`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to see code as near to human understanding as possible. That's why three forms of decisions (if-then-else, switch-case-default, ?:) are suited to map three different though processes:

- *... and now, in an event there is a frobnicated quibplatz, we should do ... (otherwise ... should be done)* is a mapping for `if` )
- *... and now based on the quibplatz value, we should do ... if it is 0, ... if it is 1 (, ... if it is none of them)* if a mapping for `switch`
- *... we use ... or ... based on the fact if ... holds or not* is mapping for `?:`

So use the one which maps to the way you think of the actual decision as a human.

Of course, it should be **stressed** that proper OO solution in lots of scenarios of *... and we do ... which we do this way for ..., this way for ... and this way for ...*, where often `switch` is used (but it holds for some `if`s as well) is to not use these constructs and replace them with polymophism. Manual decision making should only be done when there is a real decision, not to fake (logical) polymorphism.

Comment: For your example, first step if to use `switch` and second to make it a polymorphic call (since this is a faked polymorphism I wrote in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements are faster the nested if statements. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` just like `if elseif`. Too many `Switch` or `if elseif` will make your code very difficult to read and understand. But no any function issue.

Answer (score -1):

it depends on what you want to do inside it.
keep in mind you cant alloc new object inside switch statement

Comment: You can't declare local variables inside a switch unless you create a new scoping block with { and }

Comment: @progrmr that's the point. You _can_ alloc new objects inside a switch

Answer (score -3):

If 'if' and 'switch' are so evil they should have been removed from modern programming languages. The fact is they are still there. I think the key is we should try our best to make our code works correctly and efficiently, easy to understand and maintain. OOP is just one way to write programs, we shouldn't write programs for pure OOP. So it's really a subjective problem.